# Varieties over function fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field and $X$ be an irreducible algebraic variety over $k$. Let $Y$ be a variety over $k(X)$.
Is it true that we have an algebraic variety $Z$ over $k$ and a morphism $f:Z \to X$ over $k$ whose generic fiber is $Y$?

For instance $y^2 = x(x-1)(x-t)$ is an elliptic curve over $k(t)$, but I think that it also gives a surface $Z$ over $k$ and $f : (x,y,t) \mapsto t \in X = \Bbb P^1_k$. I'm not sure how to proceed in the general case.

Comment: For elliptic curves, see Proposition 1.1 in Elliptic curves over function fields, Douglas Ulmer.

Comment: See also Silverman, Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, p. 200

Comment: You might have a look at the beginning of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280793/two-definitions-of-the-narrow-mordell-weil-group?rq=1

Comment: See also Kodaira–Néron model (for elliptic curves/surfaces).

Comment: See proposition 2.1.1 in Lectures on curves and Jacobians over function fields by Douglas Ulmer for the case of curves.

Comment: I don't think that the following is what you are looking for, but maybe see Poonen's _Rational points on varieties_ : theorem 3.2.1 about **spreading out**. (See also [EGA IV3, §8.10]).

Comment: (Also, theorem IV.4.5(a) in Advanced topics... by Silverman might be nice to know).